# Resize on rotation

Tags: objective-c, rotation

I am trying to put a UIScroll view on a page that fills the page minus a 10px margin around the edge. This I have done. However, I also want the UIScrollView to resize as the device is rotated, keeping the 10px margin. My code so far is:

```
// Get the screen dimensions, considering the status bar
scrollWidth = self.getScreenSize.width   // evaluates to 1004 in landscape & 748 in portrait
scrollHeight = self.getScreenSize.height // evaluates to 728 in landscape & 984 in portrait

scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,scrollWidth,scrollHeight)];
[scrollView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];

... other stuff to load scrollview content ...

[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

When I launch the app, scrollView is wider than the page, irrespective of which orientation I launch it in. Removing the [scrollView setAutoresizingMask..... line makes the scrollView fit perfectly, but doesn't react to device rotation.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: simply set Different 3 frames for different 3 rotate position and then put condition and in that check current rotate state and according to that set particular frame for scroll that you have just made

Comment: manually change the frames of scrollview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` to detect when you screen is going to rotate, and then change the frame of the scroll view:

```
CGRect frame = scrollView.frame
//Change frame
scrollView.frame = frame;
```

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation may be deprecated, but shouldAutorotate did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

if you are targeting 6.0 or higher use AutoLayout / Constraints. Much easier than dealing with  frames and bounds and centers.